# Workflow Should Not Proceed Unless Step1 Is Met

Tags: workflow

I am a bit of a rookie with workflows. I have a series of steps, including impersonation steps that I only want to run if Step1 condition is met. How do I tell the workflow that the workflow should not continue to subsequent steps unless Step1 is met?

Comment: are you using workflow 2013 or 2010?

Comment: 2010! Would the approach be to set a status field in Step1 to In Progress, and then have each subsequent step (eg. Step2) begin with an IF Statement that the field status would need to equal In Progress?

Comment: you could use the "Wait for field to change" action, which is the best you could do, unless you want to run another workflow that will check that for you...

Answer (score 1):

Use the an if statement to set your condition, then use the Stop Workflow action to end the workflow unless the condition is met.